# How to find average of values in columns within iterrows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 100+ columns where all columns after col10 are of type float. What I would like to do is find the average of certain range of columns within loop. Here is what I tried so far,

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    a = row.iloc[col30:col35].mean(axis=0)
```

This unfortunately returns unexpected values and I'm not able to get the average of col30,col31,col32,col33,col34,col35 for every row.Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
df.iloc[:, 30:35].mean(axis=1)
```

You may need to adjust 30:35 to 29:35 (you can remove the .mean and play around to get an idea of how the .iloc works). Generally in pandas you want to avoid loops as much as possible. The .iloc method allows you to select the index and columns based on their positional index. Then you can use the .mean() with axis=1 to sum across the 1st axis (Rows).

You really should be putting a small example where I reproduce the example, please see this below where the mentioned solution in comments works.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({i:val for i,val in enumerate(range(100))}, index=list(range(100)))
for i,row in df.iterrows():
     a = row.iloc[29:25].mean() # a should be 31.5 for each row
     print(a)
```

Comment: You are right but I need to loop to create a different structure. Is there a way this can be achieved within iterrows.

Comment: a = row.iloc[29:35].mean() in your code should work.

Comment: This doesnt work, I get error ````ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019/4_1    100.0\n2019/5_1    100.0\n2019/6_1    100.0\nName: 0 dtype: object'````

Comment: When using multiple columns in iloc, I get the values along with the header which is causing it to be a string instead of float.

Comment: It looks like your columns aren't just numbers please see the reproducible example I added above, if you can give me a small snippet of you DataFrame it would be easier to get a working solution.

Comment: Thanks, there are problems with my data. I will correct them and use your snippet to try it out.